# create pyspark rdd with lambda

Tags: lambda, pyspark, rdd

I want to count the percentage of each number.

```
rdd1=sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,1,5,7,3])
```

I tried

```
rdd2=rdd1.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda current, next: (current+next))
```

and got rdd2.collect(): [(1,2),(2,1),(3,2),(4,1),(5,1),(7,1)]
then

```
percentage=rdd2.map(lambda x:(x[0],(x[1]/rdd1.count())))
print(percentage.collect())
```

it had error in print step
then I tried

```
percentage=rdd2.map(lambda x:(x[0],(x[1]/len(rdd1.collect()))))
print(percentage.collect())
```

it also had error in print step.

Comment: What is it you want to exactly do?

Comment: the percentage of each number in rdd1, like the percentage of 1 is 2/8=25%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I extract from what you said that you want the `relative frequency` of each unique member of the RDD.

```py
from operator import add

rdd1 = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,1,5,7,3])
count = rdd1.count()

rdd2=rdd1
    .map(lambda x: (x, 1))  # [(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(1,1),(5,1),(7,1),(3,1)]
    .reduceByKey(add)       # [(1,2),(2,1),(3,2),(4,1),(5,1),(7,1)]
    .mapValues( lambda vSum : vSum / count ) 

rdd2.collect()
# [(1,2/8),(2,1/8),(3,2/8),(4,1/8),(5,1/8),(7,1/8)]
```

Answer (score 2):

[SPARK-5603](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5063) says that nested RDD operations are not supported.

You cannot reference an RDD action inside a transformation:

If you call the action that is `count()` before hand, your code will work.

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,1,5,7,3])
rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda current, next: (current+next))
rdd1_len = rdd1.count()
percentage=rdd2.map(lambda x:(x[0],(x[1]/rdd1_len)))

percentage.collect()
# [(1, 0.25), (2, 0.125), (3, 0.25), (4, 0.125), (5, 0.125), (7, 0.125)]
```